# Is there any way to extract images from wikipedia based on the URL using MediaWiki

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, mediawiki, wikipedia-api

I have a wikipedia URL and want to extract every content image URL

I tried normal webscraping using BeautifulSoup where I put the URL and fetch for images with the class `"thumbimage"` to get the content images but there are pages where all images have the class `"mw-file-element"` including the wikipedia logo and unnecessary ones which means that the script imports everything
So I'm trying to find a new solution using either MediaWiki or the wikipedia API

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with MediaWiki or the Wikipedia API, but I can give you some hints about how to go with the BeautifulSoup way.

1. First thing, is that you want to restrict your extraction / scraping to only the 'article' portion of a wikipedia page.
   To do so, you can target `<main id="content">`. That will excludes the header, the footer and the navbar, leaving you with images from the article only.
2. After this, you want to check the images `alt` and `typeof` to keep only the desired ones. The images in the article all have a `typeof="mw:File/xyz` value. You could use this to determine if you want to have this type of image or not in your result set.
   ie: `typeof="mw:File/Thumb"` are the normal thumbnail / displayed images through the article
   and
   `typeof="mw:File/Frameless"` is often the 'main image' of the article, in the right box.
3. Otherwise, you could analyse the `alt` property of those images and determine  some rules that would fit with your vision of which image is right or wrong and discard them based on this.

Based on those 2 points, you should be good enough to scrape every images in an article on Wikipedia without getting too much (if any) unwanted images.

Answer (score 0):

MediaWiki has [an API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Images) for retrieving images used on a page; just use it:

```py
import requests


api_endpoint = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php'

response = requests.get(api_endpoint, {
  'action': 'query',
  'prop': 'images',
  'titles': 'Alan Turing',
  'format': 'json',
  'formatversion': 2
}).json()
images = response['query']['pages'][0]['images']

print(images)

'''
[
  {'ns': 6, 'title': 'File:20130808 Kings College Front Court Fountain Crop 03.jpg'},
  {'ns': 6, 'title': 'File:Alan Turing (5025990183).jpg'},
  {'ns': 6, 'title': 'File:Alan Turing 78 High Street Hampton blue 
plaque.jpg'},
  # ...
]
'''
```

However, this only returns the names of the files, not their URLs. If you need those, make another query:

```py
response = requests.get(api_endpoint, {
  'action': 'query',
  'titles': '|'.join(image['title'] for image in images),
  'prop': 'imageinfo',
  'iiprop': 'url',
  'format': 'json',
  'formatversion': 2
}).json()

image_1_info = response['query']['pages'][0]['imageinfo']

print(image_1_info)

'''
[
  {
    'url': 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/46/20130808_Kings_College_Front_Court_Fountain_Crop_03.jpg',
    'descriptionurl': 'https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:20130808_Kings_College_Front_Court_Fountain_Crop_03.jpg',
    'descriptionshorturl': 'https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=27976001'
  }
]
'''
```